# Browsing Hbase data in Hue through Phoenix

Tags: jdbc, hbase, hue, apache-phoenix

I am using CDH 5.4.4 and installed Phoenix parcel to be able to run SQL on hbase tables. Has anyone tried to browse that data using Hue?
I know since we can connect using JDBC connection to Phoenix, there must be a way for Hue to connect to it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current status is that we would need to add HUE-2745 and then it would show up in DBQuery / Notebook

The latest https://phoenix.apache.org/server.html is brand new and JDBC only.

If there was an HiveServer2 Thrift API or ODBC for Phoenix it would work almost out of the box in the SQL or DB Query apps. Hue could work with JDBC but there will be a JDBC connector that is GPL (so to install separately).

The Hue jira for integrating Phoenix is https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2121.